# 301 old product urls to another product

Tags: product, seo

Is there anyway to auto 301 redirect old product urls to new ones..

January always brings around alot of product changes and dont want to be overwelmed with 404 errros in WMT

I use Mass 301 redirect using a CSV but is this the best way to do it ? The problem i find with this is that you need to know the url of every product before you can change it.. Sometimes we can delete 400 products that have been discountinued

Thanks
Michael

Answer (score 1):

this is a common problem in e-commerce environments. However the problem is not that you need to know the URL of every product. The real problem is: to which product should the 'old' product redirect? There's no way Magento could know this.

To answer your question: no, it's not possible to auto 301 redirect old product urls to new ones with core Magento.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Is there a possibilty of something external to do this ?

Comment: I didn't find any extension that features this functionality. External as in 'outside of Magento': not that I know of.